# Agregar nueva row mas cercana <tr> en una tabla HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo el siguiente codigo donde puedo agregar nueva linea a una tabla en HTML, siempre me agrega en la ultima fila

Mi idea es presionar el boton `+` y asi crear una linea nueva debajo de ese mismo. La idea es poder econtrar el `<tr>` mas cercano a ese evento click.

Espero poder haberme explicado biem

Espero poder haberme explicado bien. Saludos.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#main_table').on('click', 'i.new_row', function(e) {
    var i = $('#main_table tbody tr ').length;
    var html_data = "<tr>" +
      "<td></td>" +
      "<td></td>" +
      "<td></td>" +
      "<td></td>" +
      "<td></td>" +
      "</tr>";
    $('#main_table').find('tbody').append(html_data);

  });
});
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/x-editable/1.5.0/bootstrap3-editable/js/bootstrap-editable.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/x-editable/1.5.0/bootstrap3-editable/css/bootstrap-editable.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/js/all.min.js"></script>
<table id="main_table" class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Pedido</th>
      <th>Item</th>
      <th>Cantidad a despachar</th>
      <th>Stock</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="1"></th>
      <th colspan="3"><strong>00001</strong></th>
      <th colspan="1">
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline"><label class="form-check-label" for="check_rows1"></label><i class='fa fa-plus new_row'></i> </div>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>001</td>
      <td>PRODUCTO1</td>
      <td data-name="cantidad" class="cantidad" data-type="text">50</td>
      <td>100</td>
      <td>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline"><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-   input" id="Escoge1" name="Escoge"><label class="form-check-label" for="Escoge1"></label></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>002</td>
      <td>PRODUCTO1</td>
      <td data-name="cantidad" class="cantidad" data-type="text">40</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline"><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-   input" id="Escoge1" name="Escoge"><label class="form-check-label" for="Escoge1"></label></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="1"></th>
      <th colspan="3"><strong>00002</strong></th>
      <th colspan="1">
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline"><label class="form-check-label" for="check_rows1"></label><i class='fa fa-plus new_row'></i> </div>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>004</td>
      <td>PRODUCTO2</td>
      <td data-name="cantidad" class="cantidad" data-type="text">50</td>
      <td>100</td>
      <td>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline"><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-   input" id="Escoge1" name="Escoge"><label class="form-check-label" for="Escoge1"></label></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En JQuery existe la función `after()` que te permite insertar **HTML** en el **DOM** después del elemento seleccionado. A través `this` podemos capturar el elemento que ha sido pulsado (en tu caso el `<i>`) para seguidamente ascender hasta su padre `<tr>` e insertar la fila seguidamente a ese `<tr>`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#main_table').on('click', 'i.new_row', function(e) {
    let item_id = $(this).parents('tr').data('item');
    let html_data = "<tr>" +
      "<td></td>" +
      "<td></td>" +
      "<td></td>" +
      "<td></td>" +
      "<td></td>" +
      "</tr>";
    $('[data-item="' + item_id + '"]').last().after(html_data);

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/x-editable/1.5.0/bootstrap3-editable/js/bootstrap-editable.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/x-editable/1.5.0/bootstrap3-editable/css/bootstrap-editable.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/js/all.min.js"></script>
<table id="main_table" class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Pedido</th>
      <th>Item</th>
      <th>Cantidad a despachar</th>
      <th>Stock</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr data-item="00001">
      <th colspan="1"></th>
      <th colspan="3"><strong>00001</strong></th>
      <th colspan="1">
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline"><label class="form-check-label" for="check_rows1"></label><i class='new_row'>+</i> </div>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr data-item="00001">
      <td>001</td>
      <td>PRODUCTO1</td>
      <td data-name="cantidad" class="cantidad" data-type="text">50</td>
      <td>100</td>
      <td>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline"><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-   input" id="Escoge1" name="Escoge"><label class="form-check-label" for="Escoge1"></label></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-item="00001">
      <td>002</td>
      <td>PRODUCTO1</td>
      <td data-name="cantidad" class="cantidad" data-type="text">40</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline"><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-   input" id="Escoge1" name="Escoge"><label class="form-check-label" for="Escoge1"></label></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-item="00002">
      <th colspan="1"></th>
      <th colspan="3"><strong>00002</strong></th>
      <th colspan="1">
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline"><label class="form-check-label" for="check_rows1"></label><i class='new_row'>+</i> </div>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr data-item="00002">
      <td>004</td>
      <td>PRODUCTO2</td>
      <td data-name="cantidad" class="cantidad" data-type="text">50</td>
      <td>100</td>
      <td>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline"><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-   input" id="Escoge1" name="Escoge"><label class="form-check-label" for="Escoge1"></label></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks my budda funciono genial

Comment: Solo x saber se podria agregar al final, ejemplo click en el `00001` y agregar debajo del pedido `002`

Comment: Se me ocurre que cada '<tr>' tenga en un atributo `data` del grupo al que pertenece. Por ejemplo, los pedidos *001* y *002* tendrían almacenado que pertenecen a *00001*. De esa manera podrías buscar el último elemento que pertenezca a *00001* e insertar la fila después de este.Edité mi pregunta para que lo veas en funcionamiento.